# Retrieve entries from map based on one of the key values

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have reviewed similar posts but am still failing to line things up with what i'm after.

I want to retrieve all entries from the following map where the condition a particular condition is met.

The simple map

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _playList = [
    {'songId': 1, 'setId': 1},
    {'songId': 2, 'setId': 1},
    {'songId': 3, 'setId': 1},
    {'songId': 4, 'setId': 2},
    {'songId': 5, 'setId': 3},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 4},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 5},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 6},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 7},
  ];
```

I am trying to use a method which will iterate through this map, find all entries for the int that was passed into the method and then store the results in a new array.

The method I have so far

```
Future<List<Song>> songFromCurrentSetlist (int setlistId) async {
    _playList.forEach((_) => setlistId == _playList.???);
  }
```

Clearly, a bit stuck.

Basically, if 1 is received for setlistId in the parameter list for the method, I am expecting to get back the values 1,2,3 for each of the songIds that exist for setlistId == 1.

Thank you, 
Bob

Comment: Do you mean like this? setlistId = 1; _playList.where((_list) => _list["setId"] == setlistId);

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of songs and add new songs when your setId match.

Following Example Clear your Idea.

```
void main(){ 
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _playList = [
    {'songId': 1, 'setId': 1},
    {'songId': 2, 'setId': 1},
    {'songId': 3, 'setId': 1},
    {'songId': 4, 'setId': 2},
    {'songId': 5, 'setId': 3},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 4},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 5},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 6},
    {'songId': 6, 'setId': 7},
  ];

  List<int> songs = [];
   songFromCurrentSetlist (int setlistId) async {
     _playList.forEach((index){
       if(index['setId'] == setlistId){
         songs.add(index['songId']);
       }
    });
  }

  songFromCurrentSetlist(1);

  print(songs.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Map why you not using model class 
Exp:

```
class Songs{
final int songId;
final int setId;
Songs(this.songId, this.setId);}
ListSongs> _playList
```

try using this

Comment: This would work if there was always a 1:1 relationship between song and playlist.  However, a song can technically be in more than one list, so I don't believe this would work - or I'm still possibly missing something.